# Return 1 for the first instance of a value or factor in a column in R and 0 for all other subsequent instances by adding a new column of 0s and 1s

Tags: r

Here is the sample data set.Am relatively new in R.i know i can do this in excel but the dataset is so huge it takes lots of time to run.
sample dataset:

```
Item Group   Description
Fruit        Pineapple
Fruit        Pineapple
Fruit        Orange
Vegetables   Carrots
Meat         Beef
Meat         Beef
Vegetables   radishes
Vegetables   radishes
Meat         Mutton
Cereals      Beans
Cereals      Beans
```

Required data set with an addition column Count based on column - Description

```
Item Group   Description   Count
Fruit        Pineapple      1
Fruit        Pineapple      0
Fruit        Orange         1
Vegetables   Carrots        1
Meat         Beef           1
Meat         Beef           0
Vegetables   radishes       1
Vegetables   radishes       0
Meat         Mutton         1
Cereals      Beans          1
Cereals      Beans          0
```

Please assist with an R code that can add the Count column based on the Description column

Comment: So this? `as.integer(!duplicated(df))`

Comment: Sotos, thanks for this, however, your suggestion returns all 1s , I need to add a new column  that returns 1 for the first instance of the words in Description column and 0 for all other instances of the same word

Comment: Are you sure? That doesn't sound right. I get this: `[1] 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 0`

Comment: Hi Sotos, not sure if am putting the question correctly, the third added column of 1s and 0s should only be added subject to what is contained in the second column (Description), the first column is not relevant in this.so how do you specify that you are returning 1s and 0s based on column - Description?

Comment: Simple. Just add the column, i.e. `as.integer(!duplicated(df$Description))`

Comment: Thanks Sotos, appreciated, works perfectly